# What force (in newtons) are disc brake mounts built to handle?

Tags: brakes, disc-brake

I'm testing a dropout design and wondering what the standard force is considered for disc brake mounts. Simulation of mine suggests a safety factor of 15 with 2000 newtons applied to the ISO brake tab/brackets, so I'm probably good -- but I'm curious as to what a standard might be.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but there can be forces in multiple directions so imo your question would be clearer if you'd add a drawing indicating which force vector(s) you are talking about.

Comment: *Simulation of mine suggests a safety factor of 15 with 2000 newtons applied to the ISO brake tab/brackets*  2,000 N is only about 450 lbf, so does your "safety factor of 15" mean you're anticipating your brake tabs/brackets will be subjected to only 30 lbs of force.  Or are you saying that your tabs/brackets can withstand 30,000 N of force?

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at a force of 2000N on the caliper? Also, are you modeling a mountain bike or road bike?

Comment: If you assume a mass of 100kg on a bike, slowing from speeds of 25 - 50 mph at about .25 - .3 G, on 622 wheels, on a single brake, you get to ~1100-1300 newtons. (if my math is right). I had grabbed 2,000 as a likely never-to-be-seen value, but theoretically possible, I suppose. The bike's a touring bike, likely to be running 160mm calipers.

Comment: re safety factor, I'm saying that, using CAD modeling of the dropout I've made, and simulating a 2000N load at the ISO bolt holes that support the caliper adapter, it calculates a safety factor of 15, meaning the dropout itself is over-engineered (as I intended). Wondering what the standard is -- if anyone knows. I'm assuming a safety factor of 3, but at what presumed force.

Comment: a bit of googling suggests that bicycles can brake at up to ~0.7g.

Comment: *If you assume a mass of 100kg on a bike, slowing from speeds of 25 - 50 mph at about .25 - .3 G, on 622 wheels, on a single brake, you get to ~1100-1300 newtons.*  Using .3G, the braking force at the tire/road would be about 300N.  Using a 140 mm disk, that conservatively puts the pads 5 cm from the axle centerline. The tire surface is about 33 cm from the axle centerline.  That 300N is leveraged up to 2000N, not 1100-1300.  That also ignores both .3G being awfully low and the possibility of transient force peaks that might greatly exceed 2000N (hit the edge of a pavement crack while braking)

Comment: Thanks, spreadsheet had a formula error. (Also, I'm using 160mm rotors, so the distance is 7cm, not 5). As for 0.3g being "awfully low," I doubt it. Tests of racing mtn bike/ cross riders done a while back show max potential G on a rear brake stop at 0.3G. They also show max two-brake G about 0.4g. (http://www.beckforensics.com/CMRSC14BeckBicycle.pdf) However, apparently federal regs in the US dictate bike should be able to stop at 0.5g. None of this answers the question, alas. What do the builders shoot for?